# Returning object as JSON data using Web API C#

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, dapper, webapi

I want to generate JSON data from a database table using Web API C#. The following is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fields](
    [fieldID] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [displayName] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [tenant] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [type] [varchar](250) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And having following data

```
INSERT [dbo].[Fields] ([fieldID], [displayName], [id], [tenant], [Name], [description], [type]) VALUES (N'100', N'Loan#', 18, 3, N'Loan#', N'Loan#', N'string')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Fields] ([fieldID], [displayName], [id], [tenant], [Name], [description], [type]) VALUES (N'101', N'LoanProgram', 19, 3, N'LoanProgram', N'LoanProgram', N'string')
GO
```

From this table and I want to generate a JSON in the following format using the Web API

```
{
  "100": {
        "fieldID": "100",
        "displayName": "Loan#",
        "id": 18,
        "tenant": 3,
        "name": "Loan#",
        "description": "Loan#",
        "type": "string"        
    },
    "101": {
        "fieldID": "101",
        "displayName": "LoanProgram",
        "id": 19,
        "tenant": 3,
        "name": "LoanProgram",
        "description": "LoanProgram",
        "type": "string"        
    }
}
```

Following is my API controller

```
[HttpGet("Fields/{id}/fields/")]
public Object GetFields(int id)
{
   return _fieldService.GetFields(id).Result;
}
```

I have created a class as follows

```
public class ConfiguredFields
{
    public int fieldID { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string tenant { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }        
}
```

And using Dapper I have called the SP and tried to the value

```
public async Task<Object> GetWorkflowFields(int WID)
{
    using (var db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString.Value))
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@pm_ID", WID);
        var result = await db.QueryAsync<ConfiguredFields>("SP_GetLoanFields", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        
        return result.ToList();

    }
}
```

But I am getting the JSON in the following format (with array lap and not in the desired format where fieldID wise wrapping is not there.)

```
[
    {
        "fieldID": 100,
        "displayName": "Loan#",
        "id": 18,
        "tenant": "3",
        "name": "Loan#",
        "description": "Loan#",
        "type": "string"        
    },
    {
        "fieldID": 101,
        "displayName": "LoanProgram",
        "id": 19,
        "tenant": "3",
        "name": "LoanProgram",
        "description": "LoanProgram",
        "type": "string"   
    }
    
]
```

Please suggest what all changes required here to get the JSON in desired format?
Please help me to solve this?

Comment: convert your queryable to dictionary(not to list) with fieldID as key

Comment: @Selvin can you provide one sample?

Comment: No, as there are already examples here ... also check `Enumerable.ToDictionary` official documentation ... there should be an example

Comment: On the `result`, instead of `ToList()`, you can call `ToDictionary()`. As an argument you will pass a lambda that selects the key (`fieldID` in your case). The resulting dictionary should map nicely to the json you presented. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the return type of your `GetWorkflowFields` method from `Task<Object>` to `Task<List<ConfiguredFields>>`:

   ```
    public async Task<List<ConfiguredFields>> GetWorkflowFields(int WID)
    {
        ...
    }
   ```
2. Change your model properties to have types that match the data in your database (based on the table definition you gave in your question).

   Change `fieldID` from `int` to `string`.
   Change `id` from `int` to `long`.
   Change `tenant` from `string` to `long`.

   ```
   public class ConfiguredFields
   {
       public string fieldID { get; set; }
       public string displayName { get; set; }
       public long id { get; set; }
       public long tenant { get; set; }
       public string name { get; set; }
       public string description { get; set; }
       public string type { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Change your `GetFields` controller method to convert the result from `GetWorkflowFields` to a dictionary:

   ```
    return _fieldService.GetWorkflowFields(id).Result.ToDictionary(f => f.fieldID);
   ```
4. (Optional, but recommended) Change the return type of the `GetFields` controller method to `Dictionary<string, ConfiguredFields>`.  Better yet, make the method `async`:

   ```
    [HttpGet("Fields/{id}/fields/")]
    public async Task<Dictionary<string, ConfiguredFields>> GetFields(int id)
    {
        var fields = await _fieldService.GetWorkflowFields(id);
        return fields.ToDictionary(f => f.fieldID);        
    }
   ```

Comment: what should br the return type of the api controller? dictionary or Object?

Comment: @athuman : you can use either object or public Dictionary<string,ConfiguredFields> GetWorkflowFields(int id)

Comment: It should work either way, but it is better to be explicit, so I would recommend using `Dictionary<string, ConfiguredFields>`. `object` doesn't tell you anything about what the method produces.  Also, it would be better to make the method `async` since it calls an `async` method.  I've updated my answer to show this.